# Is there a register that shows the companies with notifiable interest in a stock?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, stock-markets, limited-liability-company

I am based in the UK but the question is global where it applies.

In the UK if a company holds more than 3% of stock, they must issue an RNS stating their holdings as they have a notifiable interest.

It is possible to go through all old RNS and gain an understanding of the holders with notifiable interest, however, I am interested to know if there is a website or service that does this already.

For example, here is the UK shorts tracker:

http://shorttracker.co.uk/company/GB0001500809/all

Does anyone know if there is an notifiable interest holdings tracker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple places where you can see this.

- Company house website
- On any financial news website, if you have access e.g. [TESCO on FT](http://markets.ft.com/research/Markets/Tearsheets/Business-profile?s=TSCO:LSE)
- On any 3rd party website which supply information on companies e.g. [TESCO on Companycheck](https://companycheck.co.uk/company/00445790/TESCO-PLC/group-structure)

An observation though, FT lists down more shareholders for me than Companycheck as I pay for FT.

Comment: Compare and contrat ft v companycheck.  Companycheck seems to be hopelessly out of date.